# Eager Load lists() in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eager-loading

In Laravel 4 I use Eager Loading for a ManyToMany relationship:

```php
public function categories()
{

    return $this->belongsToMany('Category');

}
```

It returns categories like this:

```php
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "priority": 1,
            "title": "My category 1",
            "created_at": "2013-08-10 18:45:08",
            "updated_at": "2013-08-10 18:45:08"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "priority": 2,
            "title": "My category 2",
            "created_at": "2013-08-10 18:45:08",
            "updated_at": "2013-08-10 18:45:08"
        }
    ],
```

But all I need is this:

```php
    "categories": [1,2] // References category id's only
```

The Query Builder has a method called "lists" which should do the trick. But it's not working in case of an Eager Load???

```php
public function categories()
{

    return $this->belongsToMany('Category')->lists('category_id');

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code to your Model/BaseModel:

```php
/**
 * Set additional attributes as hidden on the current Model
 *
 * @return instanceof Model
 */
public function addHidden($attribute)
{
    $hidden = $this->getHidden();

    array_push($hidden, $attribute);

    $this->setHidden($hidden);

    // Make method chainable
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Convert appended collections into a list of attributes
 *
 * @param  object       $data       Model OR Collection
 * @param  string|array $levels     Levels to iterate over
 * @param  string       $attribute  The attribute we want to get listified
 * @param  boolean      $hideOrigin Hide the original relationship data from the result set
 * @return Model
 */
public function listAttributes($data, $levels, $attribute = 'id', $hideOrigin = true)
{

    // Set some defaults on first call of this function (because this function is recursive)
    if (! is_array($levels))
        $levels = explode('.', $levels);

    if ($data instanceof Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection) // Collection of Model objects
    {
        // We are dealing with an array here, so iterate over its contents and use recursion to look deeper:
        foreach ($data as $row)
        {
            $this->listAttributes($row, $levels, $attribute, $hideOrigin);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Fetch the name of the current level we are looking at
        $curLevel = array_shift($levels);

        if (is_object($data->{$curLevel}))
        {
            if (! empty($levels))
            {
                // We are traversing the right section, but are not at the level of the list yet... Let's use recursion to look deeper:
                $this->listAttributes($data->{$curLevel}, $levels, $attribute, $hideOrigin);
            }
            else
            {
                // Hide the appended collection itself from the result set, if the user didn't request it
                if ($hideOrigin)
                    $data->addHidden($curLevel);

                // Convert Collection to Eloquent lists()
                if (is_array($attribute)) // Use specific attributes as key and value
                    $data->{$curLevel . '_' . $attribute[0]} = $data->{$curLevel}->lists($attribute[0], $attribute[1]);
                else // Use specific attribute as value (= numeric keys)
                    $data->{$curLevel . '_' . $attribute} = $data->{$curLevel}->lists($attribute);
            }
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

You can use it on your Model/Collection Object like this:

```
// Fetch posts data
$data = Post::with('tags')->get(); // or use ->first()

// Convert relationship data to list of id's
$data->listAttributes($data, 'tags');
```

$data will now contain the following object store:

```
{
    "posts": [
        {
            "title": "Laravel is awesome",
            "body": "Lorem Ipsum...",
            "tags_id": [ 1, 2, 3 ]
        },
        {
            "title": "Did I mention how awesome Laravel is?",
            "body": "Lorem Ipsum...",
            "tags_id": [ 1, 2, 4 ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It also supports nested relationships:

```
// Fetch posts data
$data = Post::with('comments', 'comments.tags')->get(); // or use ->first()

// Convert relationship data to list of id's
$data->listAttributes($data, 'comments.tags');
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason it doesn't work is because when eager-loading it, using the `with` method, Laravel expects a relationship method to return a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation` object, so that it can call `get` on it. When you call `lists`, the query is already ran and what is returned instead is an array.

What you could do, to reduce the data transferring, is use the `select` method on the query, and then run a `lists` on the categories Collection. Example:

**Model.php**

```
function categories() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Category')->select('id');
}
```

**Whatever.php**

```
$posts = Post::with('Category')->get();
$categories = $posts->categories;

// List only the ids
$categoriesIds = $categories->lists('id');
```

Comment: In pseudo I use something like this: return Response::json(Post::with('Category')); So i can reference the categories like $json['categories']. Is it possible to change the $posts->categories object, instead of converting it to an Array first and then doing the JSON-encoding?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the case for *all requests* to `category` model, you can set the `visible array`

like `protected $visible = array('category_id');`

now every request to category model will retrieve `category_id` only

In your case-

```
Class Category extends Eloquent{

    protected $visible=array('category_id');
    ...
}
```

**Note-** It will return collection of `category_id`'s as an object but if you need an array you have to use `toArray()` method of query builder to get an array of `category_id`

And to get exactly what you need, you can try this

```
$cat_id=Category::all()->toArray();
$arrid=array();
array_walk_recursive($cat_id,function($value,$key) use (&$arrid){
  array_push($arrid,$value);
})
//$arrid will contain only category_id's like
//$arrid=[1,2,3];
```

Comment: That's only valid when calling the `toArray()` method though.

Comment: @Raphael_ yes, if you need an array else you will get an Object

Comment: Should prolly write that on the answer.